# Email Sending restriction

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `Groups` with multiple Groups in it, and in each group in have members, I want to restrict that if a Member-A is in two groups so send the mail once, Not two times.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

    $admin_email = "someone@example.com";
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
    $grp = $_REQUEST['grp'];

    //send email

    echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT member.email FROM member inner join member_group on member.id = member_group.member_id and member_group.group_id = '$grp'");
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($query) ){
        //"<option value='$data->id'>$data->name</option>";
        mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing `SELECT member.email` to `SELECT DISTINCT member.email` in the query.

By doing this the query will not retrieve duplicate email adresses.

more info on distinct [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)